# Search for a string in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, search, datagrid, csv, datagridview

I'm loading a CSV into a DataGridView by the following code

```
        string rowValue;
        string[] cellValue;

        if(File.Exists(textBoxFilePath.Text.ToString().Trim()))
        {
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(textBoxFilePath.Text.ToString().Trim());
        rowValue = streamReader.ReadLine();
        cellValue = rowValue.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4 - 1; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            column.Name = cellValue[i];
            column.HeaderText = cellValue[i];
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
        }
        // Reading content
        while (streamReader.Peek() != -1)
        {
            rowValue = streamReader.ReadLine();
            cellValue = rowValue.Split(',');
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            dt = DateTime.Now;
            String month = dt.Month.ToString();
            String day = dt.Day.ToString();
            if (dt.Month < 10)
            {
                month = "0" + dt.Month;
            }

            if (dt.Day < 10)
            {
                day = "0" + dt.Day;
            }
            String stringDate = dt.Year.ToString() + "/" + month + "/" + day;
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortDateString());
            Console.WriteLine(stringDate);
            if (cellValue[2].CompareTo(stringDate) == 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellValue);                    
            }
        }
        streamReader.Close();
        dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["User-Name"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No File is Selected");
        }
```

I want to search for a User-Name. Which is column 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for particular value of `User-Name` column? If so, you can handle it like this:

```
string searchedText = "some name";
var matchedRows = this.dataGridView1.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(r => r.Cells["User-Name"].Value)
    .Where(v => v != null && v.ToString() == searchedText)
    .ToList();
```

The `matchedRows` list will contain all rows that matched your search string. Note that you'll need to include `using System.Linq;` namespace for `.Cast` and `.Where` methods.

Comment: I get a NullReferenceExpection on ".Where(r => r.Cells["User-Name"].Value.ToString() == searchedText)"

Comment: @CocoaDev: you can drop `.ToString()` from `.Where` if your cells can be nulls.

Comment: My cells shouldn't be null but this isn't working. I tried partial matches and no results (even though I see them in the datagrid). I've also copied and pasted the data from the cell and searched for it.

Comment: what happens to the other rows? I want to search for a name and then filter the results. When I clear the TextBox, the DataGridView should show all the results (prior to filtering)

Comment: @CocoaDev: once you set `dataGrid.Rows` to new value old one is lost. Ideally, you want to keep original (as it was loaded from file) collection somewhere as a backup, filter that very collection with LINQ when TextBox value changes, build new rows and set it to grid. Or use data binding [filtering mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx). Both of those call for some refactoring of your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can access arbitrary cell's `value` in `DataGridView` following the pattern:

`dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value`